# Is a Yongnuo YN600EX-RT flash compatible with a Canon 550D?

Tags: flash, canon-550d, yongnuo

I want to know, if I buy a Yongnuo YN600EX-RT flash, is it compatible with a Canon 550D ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is compatible.

Of course the combination would work just fine in manual mode, but you likely are interested in some automated(evaluative) flash capabilities.

The Yongnuo YN600EX-RT flash is compatible with Canon E-TTL / E-TTL II and it is also compatible with the Canon 2.4 GHz Radio System (allowing you to pair with a 600EX-RT or ST-E3-RT).  So in essence you really lose out on almost nothing when comparing this to the vastly more expensive Canon options (there are some minor differences for those that are particular).

Comment: @KernelByte Because this is SE, and not a messageboard, consider [accepting](http://photo.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), or (when you get the rep) [upvoting](http://photo.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) an answer instead of a thanks comment. Please, take [the tour](http://photo.stackexchange.com/tour) if you plan to stick around.